# Detect TableView and CollectionView scrolling in same controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have `CollectionView` and `TableView` in a controller . I have made a `segment control` by `CollectionView` and implements `scrollView` **delegate** in `controller` like below :-

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

I have implements `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, Now i want to detect which component scrolling (tableView or collectionView)

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
         //here i want to detect which component scrolling(tableView or collectionView)

        if scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0
        {
            segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.colView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        else if scrollView.contentOffset.x == view.frame.size.width
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.colView.reloadData()
            }
            segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async{

                let segAttributes: NSDictionary = [
                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
                    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
                ]
                let segAttributes1: NSDictionary = [
                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.init(red: 247.0/255.0, green: 105.0/255.0, blue: 8.0/255.0, alpha: 1),
                    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
                ]


                self.segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(segAttributes1 as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.selected)
                self.segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(segAttributes as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.normal)
                self.tblVIewAmenities.reloadData()
                self.tblViewRoomDetails.reloadData()
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: with tag you can detect which component  is scrolling

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` inherit from `UIScrollView` you can use an `if let` to attempt to cast the `UIScrollView` to either, which will then reveal which it is:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
  func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let _ = scrollView as? UITableView {
      print("tableview")
    } else if let _ = scrollView as? UICollectionView {
      print("collectionview")
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have properties stored for the `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`, you could use an equality check on the `scrollView` passed to `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_:)` to determine which is which:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
  func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == tableView {
      print("tableview")
    } else if scrollView == collectionView {
      print("collectionview")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> **UICollectionView and UITableView** inherits from **UIScrollView**, so you can identify with name

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{

 if scrollView == collectionViewName
 {
  // its in collectionview
 }
 else
 {
  // tableview
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested on Swift4

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    switch scrollView {
    case is UITableView:            debugPrint("UITableView")
    case is UICollectionView:       debugPrint("UICollectionView")
    default:                        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with isDescendant method which returns true if the receiver is a subview of a given view or identical to that view. Let say we have references as tableView and collectionView.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.isDescendant(of: tableView)
    {
    }
    else if scrollView.isDescendant(of: collectionView)
    {
    }
}
```